# Getting 'The system cannot open the device or file specified' error when trying to change icon of .NET exe using Vestris.ResourceLib in C#

Tags: c#, .net-4.7.2

I am using Vestris.ResourceLib library in C# to change the icon of a .NET exe file. However, when I run my code, I am getting the error message 'The system cannot open the device or file specified.' I have disabled Windows Defender as a potential cause, but the issue persists. What could be causing this error and how can I resolve it?

This is my code.

```cs
// IconPath: ./icon.ico (Exists)
// OutputPath: ./test.exe (Exists)
IconFile iconFile = new IconFile(IconPath);
IconDirectoryResource iconDirectoryResource = new IconDirectoryResource(iconFile);
iconDirectoryResource.SaveTo(OutputPath);
```

What I've tried:

- Closing any running instances of the application I am trying to modify.
- Checking the file permissions of the file I am trying to modify.
- Running my application with administrative privileges.
- Disabling Windows Defender as a potential cause.
- Searching online for similar issues.

What I expected:

- I expected the code to run without any errors and for the icon of the .NET exe file to be changed successfully.

Comment: When you say that the file exists, did you check it at runtime in the variable or in Windows file explorer?

Comment: Using `File.Exists` for both the icon and the exe.